# X is number of coin flips needed to get m tails OR m heads. What is the cumulative distribution function of x?

Tags: probability, summation

So far, I know $$P(x=k)={{k-1} \choose m-1}*2^{1-k}$$ and $$\sum_{k=m}^{2m-1}{ {k-1} \choose m-1}*2^{1-k} = 1$$

Comment: I suspect no "nice" expression for the CDF, in the same way there is not for the binomial distribution or negative binomial distribution, unless you want to use the regularized incomplete beta function

Comment: Well I tried $$\sum_{k=m}^x{ {k-1} \choose m-1}*2^{1-k} $$ ,mathematica gives the answer [link](https://imgur.com/gallery/NXnt5Rw) But I can't figure out how to get to that.

Comment: Your Mathematica expression involves a hypergeometric function $\,_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$.  [Incomplete beta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) can be written as [hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) so I am not particularly surprised.   I suspect you will find either is more complicated than simply doing the sum.